# open google.navigation from URL

Tags: android, url, navigation

is there a way to start the google.navigation in Android through URL? I have a list of places in my webapp and the user should be redirected to the navigation app after clicking on navigation button in my webapp and navigate from his/her current position. Can you help me?

Comment: Add more details and code.

Answer (score 0):

See the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents)

For turn-by-turn navigation:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=a+street+address");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Comment: I've seen this, but could you be more specific, how the link should look like? For example: 

`window.open("google.navigation:q=Trnava, Slovakia");`

does not work...